# How can I prioritize a certain secrets storage mechanism (without removing / uninstalling others)?

Tags: security, keyrings

Is there a way to configure which secrets storage mechanism apps can use?

Suppose I have kdewallet, gnome-keyring and keepassXC all installed simultaneously on a system, but I want to prioritize keepassXC for example. How would I do that?

##### Why I want to do this:

Right now there's an app that I want to use ([nheko](https://github.com/Nheko-Reborn/nheko) but more specifically its Flatpak amd64 versions which can be found [here](https://matrix-static.neko.dev/room/!TshDrgpBNBDmfDeEGN:neko.dev/)) which seems to offload its private info handling to secrets storage systems like kdewallet.

While KeepassXC is primarily built for storing your password, recent versions now also feature a [Secret Service Integration](https://c3pb.de/blog/keepassxc-secrets-service.html) and can be used instead of gnome-keyring or kdewallet.

I'm trying to use KeepassXC but the app in question is complaining that it can't find kdewallet keys (which makes sense since I don't use kdewallet). Hence I want to prioritize KeepassXC so that the app tries that method first.

I'm hesitant of removing either gnome-keyring or kdewallet because I don't know what that might break.

Comment: What do you understand under "prioritizing KeepassXC"? Describe more precisely what the current behaviour is of your system, and how you would want it to behave.

Comment: Agreed. The apps you mentioned, while they are all used for secrets storage in general, they were not all designed for the same set of use cases. Keepass is for storing your passwords while the keyring is usually used by applications when asking for authentication / authorization for a privelege(s). It does store your Ubuntu password, but only for the purpose of authenticating you (making you provide it). I am sure you could use it to keep passwords, but it's main purpose is as an integral part of your operating system. This is why we are curious about the details. What type of secrets?

Comment: @vanadium: 

Right now there's an app that I want to use ([nheko](https://github.com/Nheko-Reborn/nheko) but more specifically its Flatpak amd64 versions which can be found [here](https://matrix-static.neko.dev/room/!TshDrgpBNBDmfDeEGN:neko.dev/)) which seems to offload its private info handling to secrets storage systems like kdewallet. 

While KeepassXC is primarily built for storing your password, recent versions now also feature a [Secret Service Integration](https://c3pb.de/blog/keepassxc-secrets-service.html) and can be used instead of gnome-keyring or kdewallet.

1/2

Comment: @NateT:

I'm trying to use KeepassXC but the app in question is complaining that it can't find kdewallet keys (which makes sense since I don't use kdewallet). Hence I want to prioritize KeepassXC so that the app tries that method first.

I hope this clarifies everything sufficiently. If not, please do let me know.

2/2

Comment: @ForeverNoob do not hesitate to add any clarification to the actual question: use "edit". Comments are not always read and may disappear any time. Instead of "prioritize" you may consider directly saying you want KeepasXC to manage your secret keys rather than "Passwords and Keys" (i.e. seahorse).

Comment: @vanadium: Thanks, I added clarification and also included an answer to your comment.